# Как использовать Scanner для char?

Tags: java, scanner

В классе Scanner есть для `int` метод `nextInt()`, для `double` метод `nextDouble()`, для `String` метод `nextLine()`, а какой есть для `char`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У метода next можно взять символ

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
char c = scanner.next().charAt(0);
```

Comment: почему .next().charAt(0); получается будет считывать до пробела и только 0 индекс?